# whois lookup threshold

Tags: dns

I'm trying to create an automated bulk domain name availability lookup service.  I'm wondering if there are guidelines available as to how many lookups are allowed from a single ip address in a set period of time?

### Edit

To add further clarification I am automating using multiple calls to the command terminal whois command, not through any particular website.

Comment: the limits vary with the service you use - these service are commercial, so they charge for bulk use or use of their API.

Comment: I have added further clarification to my original question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whois bulk lookup limitations are usually enforced on the source IP seen by the whois server in the query. The solution is to bounce around as many IPs as possible by using proxies, server farms, web based whois forms, etc.

Comment: I'm not trying to fool the service by bouncing around on different IP addresses.  Rather just looking for an allowed limit so I can throttle requests to an allowable amount.  I'm wanting to use the service within the permitted rules from a single ip address.

Comment: Varies from each provider. Most country specific tlds are easy to find, the .com ones are a different kettle of fish as the first query returns a secondary whois server to query which is controlled by the individual registrar who are free to set arbitrary limits. Major registrars usually have their limits mentioned in some FAQ, otherwise you can always try asking, or track how many queries you get in before you're temporarily banned.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I basically just throttled my app way down, then just kept upping little by little.

Answer (score 0):

Each registry/Registrar has its own throttle rule, as an example: godaddy only allows 100 or less queries from any IP.